# Running OutOfMemory with ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory, heap-memory, executorservice

I have a couple of questions regarding the right way to use ExecutionCompletionService. My current implementation is as follows:

```
int[] numThreads = new int[]{1,2,4,8,16};
for(int currThreads: numThreads) {
   ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean> completionService;
   ExecutorService myExecutors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(currThreads);
   completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean>(myExecutors);
   List<Future<Boolean>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Boolean> myResults = new ArrayList<>();
   try {
   for(int i=0; i<currThreads; i++) {
       futuresList.add(completionService.submit(
           () -> {
                //Some logic
                return result;
             }
       ));
   }
   for(int i=0; i<currThreads; i++) {
       myresults.add(futuresList.get(i).get());
   }
   for(int i=0;i<myresults.size; i++) {
       if(!myresults.get(i)){
       //throw exception
       }
   }
   } finally {
      myResults.clear();
      myExecutors.shutdown();
      myExecutors.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }
}
```

I am getting an OutOfMemory error where I call `Future.get()` method. What is wrong with my implementation here?
Will using `completionService.take().get()` make a difference as opposed to the `Future.get()`

Second,
Is it advisable to initiate the pool once outside the for loop? Since I know the maximum number of threads I am going to spawn.

Here is how the stacktrace looks like:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (failed to allocate 3997712 bytes)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at test.app.TestApp.main ....
```

Comment: Code executes without any error. What is the thing you are calculating in your `some logic` part?

Comment: It's a bunch of jdbc inserts into a database @TwoThe

Comment: Do you get the same error if you comment out that code?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but if I do that there is no logic left really

Comment: That's the point. Just do something like `return random.nextBoolean()` so the JVM will not optimize that away. If the issue is then gone, you know where to look.

Comment: It works fine with random.nextBoolean( )

Comment: Then your problem is in the jdbc code.

Comment: @TwoThe What about the other two questions? Does it make sense to initialize the completionService outside the for loop? Also is `completionSerivce.take().get()` better than `futuresList.get(i).get()`?

Comment: Using `ExecutorService.invokeAll` and some streams you can probably remove a lot of code. Sadly I currently do not have the time for a more detailed answer.